# assertion firing in lvm::IRBuilder::checkGEPType()

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api

I got this code written for me by chatgpt. Originally it didn't compile potentially because of my LLVM version is younger -- IRBuilder::CreateGEP() required another argument.

I'm trying to write into an array contained inside a struct.
This works fine, as long as one writes to the first index of the array -- but anything larger than 0 causes this assertion.

Anybody any clue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include "llvm/ADT/ArrayRef.h"
#include "llvm/IR/IRBuilder.h"
#include "llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Module.h"
#include "llvm/IR/Verifier.h"

using namespace llvm;

static constexpr std::size_t SIZE = 3;

static Type*createStructType(LLVMContext& _r)
{   return StructType::create(
        {   ArrayType::get(Type::getDoubleTy(_r), SIZE)
        },
        "DualNumber"
    );
}

int main(int, char**) 
{
    LLVMContext sContext;
    Module sModule("example", sContext);
    IRBuilder<> sBuilder(sContext);

    auto const pDualNumberType = createStructType(sContext);

    // Define a function that multiplies two dual numbers.
    auto const pMultiplyType = FunctionType::get(
        pDualNumberType,
        {   pDualNumberType->getPointerTo(),
            pDualNumberType->getPointerTo()
        },
        false
    );
    auto const pFunction = Function::Create(
        pMultiplyType,
        Function::ExternalLinkage,
        "multiply",
        sModule
    );
    auto const pBB = BasicBlock::Create(
        sContext,
        "entry",
        pFunction
    );
    sBuilder.SetInsertPoint(pBB);


    // code written by chatgpt starts here
    // Create a struct type that contains an array of 10 double values
    std::vector<llvm::Type*> structElements;
    structElements.push_back(llvm::ArrayType::get(llvm::Type::getDoubleTy(sContext), 10));
    llvm::StructType* structType = llvm::StructType::create(sContext, structElements, "myStruct");

    // Create an instance of the struct on the stack
    llvm::AllocaInst* structInstance = sBuilder.CreateAlloca(structType);

    // Get a pointer to the second element of the array in the struct
    std::vector<llvm::Value*> indices;
    indices.push_back(llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(sContext), 0));
    indices.push_back(llvm::ConstantInt::get(llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(sContext), 1));
    llvm::Value* arrayPtr = sBuilder.CreateGEP(structType->getPointerTo(), structInstance, indices);

    // Store a double value into the second element of the array
    llvm::Value* doubleValue = llvm::ConstantFP::get(llvm::Type::getDoubleTy(sContext), 3.14);
    sBuilder.CreateStore(doubleValue, arrayPtr);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to select an element of an array contained inside a struct one needs to pass 3 indices to IRBuilder::CreateGEP().

The first index value is always zero, assuming that there is only a single structure and not an array of structures.

The second index value selects the element inside the structure, which is zero as there is only a single element.

And finally comes the index selecting the element inside the array!

Also the first argument to CreateGEP() must be the type of the struct, but not a pointer to a struct.

```
llvm::Value* arrayPtr = sBuilder.CreateGEP(
    structType,
    structInstance,
    {   llvm::ConstantInt::get(
            llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(sContext),
            0/*the first element of an array of structs of length one*/
        ),
        llvm::ConstantInt::get(
            llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(sContext),
            0/*selecting first element in the struct*/
        ),
        llvm::ConstantInt::get(
            llvm::Type::getInt32Ty(sContext),
            0/*index into the array*/
        )
    }
);
```